# How Jenkins master instructs slave to download source from TFS

Tags: windows, jenkins, plugins, tfs, slave

DevOps configured a windows slave machine as build machine for our team, and I noticed that he installed TFS plug in Jenkins master ,but not slave machine. However we do get source code in the slave afterwards.
I wonder how the download workflow works? :

- 1) Master downloads source code and then transfers code to slave
  machine ?
- 2) or after Master connects to TFS server, then it just instructs slave machine to download it from TFS server directly?

Please explain a bit the mechanism. If it is 2), then what is installed in slave to be able to download from TFS.

Answer (score 0):

[VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) plugins usually work this way:

1. Master is configured to use some VCS and prepared with some settings
2. Slave has some binaries that are able to execute download command

After a build start, most steps will be executed on slave via its binaries, including downloading of source code. This requires slave to has VCS binary (for example, `git`) and access to target repository (for `git` it may be ssh key).

I don't have any slave with TFS at hand right now, but the process is pretty same. I suppose if you check `Console output` of build, you'll see the full path to binary used for TFS download somewhere at the very top.

Here is a sample of such output for git:

```
Building remotely on slave01 in workspace /jenkins-workspace
> /bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> /bin/git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:ORG/repo.git # timeout=10
```

Comment: Following is my output, and i can't tell who ( master or slave ) downloads it    -------Building remotely on BuildSlaveV1(EUDCCESBUILDVM) (CES) in workspace C:\J\workspace\CES_Team\YuTest2 Querying for remote changeset at '$/Client/000MSBuild' as of 'D2017-02-21T19:57:56Z' <br/> Query result is: Changeset #32379 by 'ADVENT\yzheng' on '2017-02-21T19:57:41Z'.<br/> Listing workspaces from http://10.64.128.57:8080/tfs/CES...

Comment: Nothing really useful here. Perhaps TFS plugin doesn't give us that much detailed output.

Answer (score 0):

To establish a communication between Jenkins and TFS, you need to install [Team Foundation Server Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin) and configure it as [this article](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin#400-and-later-new) states. In this way, Jenkins can get resources from TFS.

Each slave runs a separate program called a "slave agent", the slave agent and Jenkins master needs to establish a bi-directional communication link.
To set up slaves/nodes in Jenkins, you can refer to [this article](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines). If all the settings all entered correctly, the node slave machine will be online and communicate with Jenkins master.

Comment: I have just read them all. As the artical states, after install TFS plug-in(4.0), Jenkins master download sources files from TFS server and sends over to slave machine. before 4.0, Jenkins slave will need to install tf.exe etc to download source file itself. If my understanding is correct, then actually installing TFS plug-in 4.0, Jenkins master will do a lot of downloading work, slave would just do building work. I actually thought Jenkins master should not do any actual downloading work, but just delegate to slave.